# qt json encode associative array and objects

Tags: c++, json, qt, encode

After searching found nothing suitable,
I need to encode string to json like json_encode in php, but in Qt. Does Qt support json encoding? Or should I use third-party library?
I need to encode something like:

```
array(
    'SourceLanguage' => 'autodetect',
    'Source' => array(
                    'Extension' => '.pdf',
                    'Content' => 'somecontent'
                ),
                'ProcessingTimeout' => 1000,
                'UserDomainModelName' => ''
);
```

PS: Something like JsonObject, JsonArray, JsonValue I found but their documentation with no examples killing me, please help

Comment: Are you sure you was mind about `encode` and not `decode` ?

Comment: @VictorPolevoy, I'm sure the OP meant encode. You wouldn't be able to decode the given structure, as it is not valid JSON.

Comment: yes, sure Victor, yeah, right Merlin

Answer (score 0):

> encode string to json like json_encode in php

As the array you provide in the example is not a string, but a php data type, Qt would not know how to encode the string representation of that.

If you want to encode that data directly, you could do something like this, starting by building up the inner array: -

```
QJsonObject innerArrayObject;
innerArrayObject["Extension"] = QString(".pdf");
innerArrayObject["Content"] = Qstring("somecontent");

QJsonArray innerArray;
innerArray.append(innerArrayObject);

QJsonObject content;
content["SourceLanguage"] = QString("autodetect");
content["source"] = innerArray;
content["ProcessingTimeout"] = 1000;
content["UserDomainModelName"] = QString("");

QJsonArray outerArray;
outerArray.append(content);
```

You can then add the top level array to a QJsonObject (root object), place it in a document and print out the contents

```
QJsonObject obj;
obj["root"] = outerArray;

qDebug() << QJsonDocument(obj).toJson(QJsonDocument::Compact);
```

Comment: No problem, let us know how you get on.